# Thought Leaders OF or Thought Leaders IN Physics?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the two is correct or more natural?

Comment: From the [tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info): **Please also provide as much details as you can about the intended context or meaning.** "Which is correct or more natural" is unanswerable without knowing what you intend to say -- the community can then advise on the right preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are in current use as Google Books (do not use vanilla Google) shows:

["among Thought Leaders **of**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Thought%20Leaders%20IN%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22among%20Thought%20Leaders%20of%22)
About 26 results

["among Thought Leaders **in**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Thought%20Leaders%20IN%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22among%20Thought%20Leaders%20IN%22)
About 78 results

IMO, "in" is **more democratic, inclusive and less remote/abstract**, but that's just my take.

It's also 3x more frequent, something perhaps not to be neglected.